# A count given by CountVectorizer is different from manual counting

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe of a single column ("strings") that contains words (no punctuation). I need to count the number of rows a certain word (in the example below, the word: "problem") appears in this dataframe.

First, I created a column for each word, counted the number of times each word appears in each row and counted the number of rows with positive values for "problem". That is `method1_outcome`.

Then, I used sklearn's built-in CountVectorizer object to transform the same dataframe rows into a sparse matrix and counted the positive values of the column that corresponds to "problem" (`method2_outcome`).

The problem is these values don't match. And the difference is not small either. `method2_outcome` is greater by more than 11%. What's going on here? I looked into the documentation for CountVectorizer but couldn't find an answer.

The first method:

```
for word in some_words:
    df[word] = df['strings'].apply(lambda s : s.split().count(word))
method1_outcome = np.count_nonzero(df['problem'].values)
```

The second method:

```
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=some_words) 
word_matrix = vect.fit_transform(df['strings'])
ind = vect.vocabulary_['problem']
method2_outcome = np.count_nonzero(word_matrix[:,ind].toarray())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see this happening is that some of your words were uppercase/capitalized. By default, `CountVectorizer` is `lowercase=True`, so probably that your own approach counted the uppercase/capitalized words as separate. Try:

```
df[word] = df['strings'].apply(lambda s : s.lower().split().count(word))
```